# Wrong number of arguments error when initialising with options hash

Tags: sql, ruby, oop

Time to ask the experts. I am trying to seed my database. The code below gives me a wrong number of arguments error to create the 'category' object. This is the first time this error raises during object creation in this file.

```
@category1 = Category.new( {'description' => 'food'} )
@category1.save
```

This is what my category model looks like..

```
class Category

attr_reader :id,  :description, 

def initialize(options)
@id = options['id'].to_i
@description = options['description']
end
```

```

Apperently it expects zero arguments. But I am initialising it with the options hash. I.d comes later from SQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `def initialize(**options)`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: nah, that's not the problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is right, that isn't helping.

Comment: I have seeded the db many times this way. This one time the argument error is raised. Odd...

Answer (score 1):

I found problem

remove comma in the end of `attr_reader` list:

```
attr_reader :id,  :description,
```

to

```
attr_reader :id,  :description
```

PS

just typo

Comment: godhar, I suggest you wait awhile before selecting an answer. You don't want to discourage other answers or short-circuit those still working on answers. There's no rush. Oleg, asking that your answer be upvoted and selected by the OP, especially so soon after the question has been posted, is unseemly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the trailing comma at the end of your attribute reader definitions with attr_reader.

If you change it from this:

```
  attr_reader :id,  :description,
```

to this:

```
  attr_reader :id, :description
```

it should work fine (at least it did in my tests).

AFAICT the reason is that with the comma the whole definition becomes an argument to the attr_reader method. Not sure what it does with that argument (that can probably only tell a more expert rubyist),
but in the result your class does not have an initializer method accepting any arguments.